# Microsoft Extensions Logging with ASP.NET MVC 4 Web app and dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-extensions-logging

We have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app and I am trying to add Microsoft Extension logging using dependency injection methodology but unable to do.

Here is my `BaseController` where I am trying to initiate `ILoggerFactory` property which I wish to use across all controllers as they inherits from `BaseController`. I am not sure if this is right way in ASP.NET MVC because I am able to do in .NET Core.

[image]